# How to make predictions for a single image in a classification model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, google-colaboratory, prediction

I followed a few colabs and am able to train a model and evaluate its accuracy. However, it doesn't show how to make predictions for a single input. I just want to test the model to predict a new example not a batch of examples.

When I use `model.predict(image)` where the image is the NumPy array of an image I am getting this error

`Error when checking input: expected keras_layer_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1)`

How do I predict a single image and find its class?

Link to my colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dBwo43ULo99FsUQoxYRsaATIpCANPtkh

Comment: please post your keras model input code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a batch of size 1 by expanding the first dimension:

```py
image = np.expand_dims(image, 0)
```

That being said, your image should be of shape `(height, width, channels)` or `(channels, height, width)` to start with, but that is not the case judging from the error message you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But now I'm getting this error 
Expected keras_layer_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 2). The shape has changed to (1,2) from (2,1) but the expected input must have 4 dimensions. What should I do for that?

Comment: As others suggested, there is likely an error in how you create the input. Can you edit your original question to show where `image` comes from?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've shared my colab in the post. Kindly look into it.

Comment: You're returning two objects from your `format_image` function, you need to do the assignment like this: `image, _ = format_image(image)`.

Comment: Oh!! Yeah... My bad. Got the result. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the image you are trying to send to model is not the format it expects

You may need to do the same preprosessing (reshaping, 
scaling etc) for your input data as for the data that was used for training

Should you share the training code, we can give details on what exactly needs to be done

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've shared my colab in the post. Kindly look into it.